# Capturing print jobs to be printed into an Image file

Tags: windows, driver, device-driver, postscript

I am a novice to Windows printer driver, and would appreciate any pointers on the following.

- Enumerating as a printer (In the
  print menu, similar to print to PDF
  file)
- Capturing the print job and encode it
  into a JPG file (say)

I am comfortable with JPG encoding, as I am thinking of using open source tools like ImageMagick.
But **I am not sure where to start the enumeration and printing stuff**.

BTW, Is Microsoft WDM DDK available for free download?

Answer (score 1):

The [Windows Driver Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/wdk/default.mspx) can be downloaded freely on [MSDN.com](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2105564e-1a9a-4bf4-8d74-ec5b52da3d00&displaylang=en)

I'm no driver expert but have worked on Printer Port Monitors (see this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901766/writing-windows-port-monitor-basics)) to capture the output of standard printer drivers (Postscript) and convert them to PDF or TIF using [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) (Ghostscript is available in an open source format, and can also output JPG) which is reasonably easy to do.

Comment: can you provide the small code for the solution you've suggested here to convert receipts to PDF while click print option in POS machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should use WMI to enumerate prints. 
See: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10539/Making-WMI-Queries-In-C
To capture all print jobs as a file, it makes more sense to capture print jobs into a pdf file, as a print job might be more than one page. To do so, you need to include in your software a .pdf library. Try: http://libharu.sourceforge.net/